# PictureBox animation freezing while Task running

Tags: vb.net, task

My Winforms application shows an animated gif inside a picturebox while long running operations run. However, it freezes while waiting for the completion of the task:

```
Public Class MyUserControl
    Sub Initialize()
        Dim folderscantask = Task.Factory.StartNew(
            Function() EwsManagedApiScanFolderHierarchy(),
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
            )
        folderdictask.Wait()
        Dim folderscanresult = folderscantask.Result
    End Sub

    Function EwsManagedApiScanFolderHierarchy() As Dictionary(Of String, String)
        'Performs a long, recursive operation involving a
        'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService object
    End Function
End Class
```

What should I do differently in order to keep PictureBox's animation running?

## EDIT

This is a more complete description of my problem, and this time I used Async/Await (since I was taught that `Task.Wait()` would block the caller thread). Now, animation moves fine until it reaches `MyUserControl.BuildFolderMenus()` for the first time, then it freezes. Is this inevitable? I mean, don't animations run in a dedicated thread?

```
Public Class MyForm : Inherits Form

    'Form has a PictureBox named PictureBoxWaiting that shows an animated gif

    Public Async Sub MyButton_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles MyButton.Click
        PictureBoxWaiting.Show()
        PictureBoxWaiting.BringToFront()
        Await MyUserControl1.Initialize()
        PictureBoxWaiting.Hide()
        MyUserControl1.Show()
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class MyUserControl

    Public Async Function Initialize() As Task
        Dim folderdic = Await GetFolderHierarchyAsync()
        BuildFolderMenus(ToolStripDropDownButtonFolders, folderdic)
    End Function

    Public Async Function GetFolderHierarchyAsync() As Task(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))
        Return Await Task.Factory.StartNew(
            Function() EwsManagedApiScanFolderHierarchy(),
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
            )
    End Function

    Function EwsManagedApiScanFolderHierarchy() As Dictionary(Of String, String)
        'Performs a long, recursive operation involving a
        'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService object
    End Function

    Private Sub BuildFolderMenus(menu As ToolStripDropDownItem, dic As Dictionary(Of String, String))
        'This reads the dictionary containing the folder hierarchy
        'and recursively adds menu items in order that folders´
        'subfolders correspond to subitems inside an item
        '
        'This must run in UI thread since it creates UI controls
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Your call to `folderdictask.Wait()` will block the current thread until the task completes, so you're not exactly running this asynchronously. Look into [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

Comment: Async/Await was my first approach but it would make run flow return from the method too early, before the folder hierarchy was scanned and the corresponding menu items added yo the ui

Comment: Then there was something you didn't do quite correctly, but it's what you've got to use if you want to wait for a task at a specific line. Of course, in its current state you could also just switch back to the old [**`ContinueWith()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx) approach.

Comment: I think you should rather focus on why your async/await approach didn't work, than trying to fix your current code as async/await is a very simple and powerful way of carrying out asynchronous work. Perhaps the recursion was part of the problem?

Comment: Dont sweat the downvote - I would say it's on-topic personally

Comment: @DavidWilson : I didn't downvote nor VTC, if you're thinking it was me :). I agree with you that it's on-topic. It's definitely not caused by a typographical error, that's for sure.

Comment: @VisualVincent No I certainly didn't think it was you - didn't even occur to me. :)

Comment: Certainly it wasn't anyone who cared to try and help. Thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are blocking the UI thread by calling `Task.Wait()`. You need to use Asunc/Await pattern. For example create a method like this:

```
Public Async Function MyFunction() as Task
    Await Task.Run(Sub()
                        ' Do something non-UI which is time-consuming
                        ' This code runs in another thread without blocking UI
                        ' For example Thread.Sleep(5000)
                    End Sub)
    'The code here runs is UI thread
End Function
```

And then as the usage:

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Await MyUserControl1.MyFunction()
End Sub
```

Then you will see, although you have a time-consuming task in `MyFunction`, but the UI will not be blocked while the task is running.

Comment: Note to @VBobCat: To return something from an asynchronous function make the return type `Task(Of yourType)`, in your case: `Async Function EwsManagedApiScanFolderHierarchy() As Task(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))`